# Reference Parent inside Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with this structure:

```
create table Products
(
    Id int identity not null 
        constraint primary key clustered (Id),
    Name nvarchar (200) not null,
)
```

I need to allow a `Product` to reference another `Product`.

The objective is, when listing products, to show one alternative to some products.

I could add a FK named `ProductId` to the `Products` table, but I have a few questions:

1. Does the circular reference create a problem?
2. How to prevent `Id` and `ProductId` to be the same? I do not want a product to reference itself.

Comment: A FK referencing itself is no problem for SQL Server. You will have to decide if your conceptual design supports that. You could write a trigger that verifies a FK is not referencing itself and then roll back the edit/insert operation if that happens.

Comment: Are you sure that _show one alternative_ will always be the case? Often this will expand to show 2, 3, 5, etc. alternatives.  You could consider using a separate table linking products with recommended alternatives to achieve this

Comment: @Martin Yes, because in this case the alternative is a replacement and I am sure only one alternative by product will be approved. In fact I cannot have even two.

Answer (score 3):

You can put an alternate in the same table like this:

```
create table Products ( 
   ProductId int identity(1, 1) primary key,
   Name nvarchar(200) not null,
   Alternate_ProductId int references Products(ProductId),
   check (Alternate_ProductId <> ProductId)
);
```

Note that in SQL Server, the primary key is clustered automatically, so there is no reason to be explicit.  Also, by definition, the primary key is not NULL, so `NOT NULL` is redundant.

Check constraints let `NULL` values pass through (unlike `WHERE` and `CASE WHEN`), so you don't have to worry about `NULL` values for `Alternate_ProductId`.

Does this cause problems?  Well, this only allows one alternate product, and that might not be sufficient.  Also, this enables chains of alternate products which could get cumbersome in the future.

Comment: Yeah, I'd almost suggest an alternate design with an "AlternateProduct" mapping table, mapping products to alternate products. This would allow one-to-many mappings, and eliminate the self-reference issue which can sometimes be a pain.

Comment: I could have an Alternate table but in fact one product will have only one alternate so having a second table might be overhead? And yes, I admit that having only one table might have some problems when deleting and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I think one essential question is what specifically you're trying to model:

- For any given product, there can be 1 (or more) alternate/equivalent products ("just as good").
- For any given product *category*, there is one **preferred** product.

For the first option, @Gordon's answer will certainly suffice (as long as you only need 1 alternate per product). If a product can have multiple alternates, you either need a "Alternate Product" mapping table (as suggested by @pmbAustin) or (assuming you have product categories) simply show other products in the same category.

For Option 2 (again, assuming you have product categories, or something similar), you can store a category's preferred product:

```
CREATE TABLE ProductCategories
(
    category_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    category_name NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    preferred_product INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Products(Id)
);

That way, if the user is looking at a "non-preferred" product, they can be shown the preferred product for that category (if it's defined).
```

Comment: I am trying to model one optional alternative to each product. And can be only one because only one will be approved.

Comment: @Miguel: Then it sounds like @Gordon's answer is better. Just be aware that you might run into circular issues (where `Product A` is an alternative to `Product B`, and vice versa).